# a.touches.item is not a function Error on touching AmCharts report in Ipad

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Here's the screenshot of the error popup displayed in iPad on touching the chart:-

[image]

**Component :**

```
<aura:component access="public">

        <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', $Resource.amChart,
                               $Resource.funnel,
                               $Resource.lightJs)}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/>

       <aura:attribute name="questionResponse" type="Map" access="public" 
            default="{'questionLablel' : 'which is your favourite food?',
                      'answer' : [{'title' : 'meals', value : '3'}, 
                                  {'title' : 'dosa', value : '2'}] }"/>

        <aura:attribute name="showLegend" type="Boolean" access="public" default="false"/>

        <lightning:card variant="narrow" title="{!v.questionResponse.questionLablel}" class="slds-m-around_small">

            <div class="eclair-component-container">
                <div id="chart1" aura:id="chart">
                    <div style="position: relative;">
                        <div id="div2" aura:id="chartdiv" class="sizeOfFunnel"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div aura:id="legend" data-ngname="legend_chart_1">
                        <div style="position: relative;">
                            <div id="div1" aura:id="legendContainer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a onclick="{!c.showLegends}">{!v.showLegend ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} Legend</a>


                </div>
            </div>

        </lightning:card>

    </aura:component>
```

**Controller.js :**

```
({
    scriptsLoaded : function(cmp, event, helper){

        var chartDiv = cmp.find("chartdiv").getElement();
        var legendContainer = cmp.find("legendContainer").getElement();

        window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function(){
            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( chartDiv, {
                "type": "funnel",
                "theme": "light",
                "dataProvider": cmp.get("v.questionResponse").answer,            
                "valueField": "value",
                "titleField": "title",
                "marginRight": 240,
                "marginLeft": 50,
                "startX": -500,
                "depth3D": 100,
                "angle": 40,
                "outlineAlpha": 1,
                "outlineColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "outlineThickness": 2,
                "labelPosition": "right",
                "labelText" : "[[title]]",
                "balloonText": "<b>[[value]]</b>",
                "legend": {
                    "divId" : legendContainer,
                    "position" : "absolute",
                    "top" : 60+"px",
                    "left" : 40+"px",
                    "periodValueText" : "[[value.sum]]"
                },
            } );
            var chart = cmp.find("chart");
            $A.util.addClass(chart, "eclair-component-chart");
            $A.util.addClass(cmp.find("legend"), "slds-hide");
        }), 0);    
    },
    showLegends : function(cmp, event, helper){
        $A.util.toggleClass(cmp.find("legend"), "slds-hide");
        cmp.set("v.showLegend", !cmp.get("v.showLegend"));
    }
})
```

**Styles :**

```
.THIS .sizeOfFunnel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.THIS .position {
    float : right !important;
}

.THIS .sizeOfFunnel a{
    display : none !important;
}

.THIS .eclair-component-container{
    __display: inline-block; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.THIS .eclair-component-chart{
    __display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: width .6s;
    transition: width .6s;
}
```

Resources :

[amChart](https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js)
[funnel](https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/funnel.js)
[lightJs](https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js)